# Traversing MS Word docx with Apache POI and identity the sequence of Tables, images and other elements

Tags: java, image, apache, ms-word, apache-poi

Im trying to traverse the docx file with Apache POI, See the following code

```
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sample1.docx");
         XWPFDocument xdoc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
         Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = xdoc.getBodyElementsIterator();
         int count=0;
         while(iter.hasNext()) {
             IBodyElement element=iter.next();
             if(element instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                 System.out.println("Paragraph\t");
             }
             if(element instanceof XWPFPictureData) { // if(element instanceof XWPFPicture) { 
                 System.out.println("Picture");
             }if(element instanceof XWPFTable) {
                 System.out.println("Table");
             }
             count++;
         }
         System.out.println("Items Found " + count);
```

Below is the input docx i used

[image]

**And my result is:**

Paragraph
Paragraph
Paragraph
Paragraph
Paragraph
Table
Paragraph
Paragraph
Paragraph
Items Found 9

**The problem is**

I m not able to retrieve the position of the picture still able to manage to get the position of the table in the given sample file.
(element instanceof XWPFPictureData) or (element instanceof XWPFPicture)
both of these are not getting me there.
Somehow my mistake is I m not using the proper type for the picture I think, then which type I have to use to get the picture position.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the following code

```
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("sample1.docx");
         XWPFDocument xdoc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
         List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs=xdoc.getParagraphs();
         for(XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {         
             for(XWPFRun run : para.getRuns()) {
                 System.out.println(run.getEmbeddedPictures().size());
             }
         }
```

The above code returns the number of images in the paragraph. Actually the thing is, in the XML encoding the XWPFPicture itself is encoded in XWPFParagraph, where in the case the tables are not. So we need this indirect method to find whether the paragraph contains the image or not and by doing so we are able to identify if the paragraph contains a picture/image and identify the position of the picture or the paragraph in which the picture is found.